# Calling model inside view or sharing with all views

Tags: laravel

I am wondering what are differences between this:

1. Make your own BaseController and extend laravel's controller. Then extend this one in every other controller and pass some data to all views.

   class BaseController extends Controller {
       public function __construct() {
           $user = User::all();
           View::share('user', $user);
       }
   }
2. Simply use this inside view

   @php
   $chats = App\Messages::all();
   @endphp

I have an chat app where I display all conversations, but I am wondering is there a better solution to share Messages model to all views where it is used?

In my case I include file with chat html into all views and only in that file I call Messages model inside `@foreach`

UPDATE: Seems like I cant convert code into code block here :/
Try to edit it... I cant

Comment: Based on the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#sharing-data-with-all-views this is suggested way of sharing data. I would rather do it either with BaseController as you mentioned or like the documentation instead of putting in the view, because for now your call is simple, but if you had to change it later on, the business logic does not belongs to the view in my opinion.

Comment: You cannot add it in AppServiceProvider if it contains db data, which from my case does. Because boot method is started before db connection. Well you can do your logic inside model and use it like (new Message)->someMethod() to move logic from view.. I mean writing that or just $message doesnt seem to be big difference